# How to Retrieve a Single-File WSDL for a WCF Service (Flat WSDL)

Tags: wcf, wsdl

i need single file wsdl,

how to build single file wsdl?

Thanks.

Comment: Could you give some more information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

install 
http://wcfextras.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 34):

You can now do this natively in .net 4.5 (beta).  There is an option (?singleWsdl  instead of ?wsdl) for telling the service to output everything in a single wsdl document. 
More info on the new stuff here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456789(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

[Bing!](http://www.bing.com/search?q=flat+wsdl&FORM=QBHP)
Four of the first five links are helpful.

Also: [flatten-your-wsdl-with-this-custom-servicehost-for-wcf](http://blogs.msdn.com/dotnetinterop/archive/2008/09/23/flatten-your-wsdl-with-this-custom-servicehost-for-wcf.aspx)

Comment: Wow, Sam you're very dissatisfied. To respond directly: (1) I still think the links are helpful. (2) The fact that a question has been asked is not proof that easy answers are not available in search engines. (3) I'm not sure what you mean by "the programming community" and its judgments; you provide no basis for that claim. (4) Your implicit claim that "this question keeps coming up" is similarly unfounded. Maybe it keeps coming up *for you*, because you haven't understood the answers that have been available since 2006. I wish you good luck and a more positive attitude in the future.

Comment: yeah, you're right actually. :-) I think you just made my point. I understood them, but I was really put off by the lack of support by a conventional method such as (1) Tools menu, (2) right-click popup menu in Solution Explorer, (3) SvcUtil.exe switch, (4) app.config Configuration GUI, or (5) Use a wizard to Configure the WSDL generation options. I certainly am dissatisfied with the method itself, not necessarily the availability of "helpful links" to that *lame* method.

Comment: Ironically, this question is now the fifth result in bing and was also the first result in google.