# Flat WSDL for WCF 4 Service

Tags: wcf, wsdl, wcf-4

Using WCF 3.5 and the [FlatWsdl EndpointBehavior from Christian Weyer](http://weblogs.thinktecture.com/cweyer/2007/05/improving-wcf-interoperability-flattening-your-wsdl.html), I was able to get a single flat WSDL file for my WCF services without any `<import>` directives.

Now with WCF 4, this doesn't work anymore for some reason.

I have tried everything described in a lot of blog entries including using the [WcfExtras](http://wcfextras.codeplex.com/) behavior extension.

They all either refer to Chr. Weyers solution or recommend the WcfExtras. 
I also made sure I specified the same namespace for the binding, ServiceContract and ServiceBehavior.

In the custom service host, when the FlatWsdlExtension is about to be injected, the Description.Endpoints collection is always empty. I tried to configure my service endpoint with or without an adress, so far without luck.

What do I need to do in order to get a single flat WSDL for my WCF 4 service?

Thanks for any answers.

Comment: For reference, this is now supported natively in .net 4.5. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/8656173/26167

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. About time this is part of the framework!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was having this **exact** problem.  After several attempts today, I finally got it to work by doing the following:

> [Read this blog post in full.](http://weblogs.thinktecture.com/cweyer/2007/05/improving-wcf-interoperability-flattening-your-wsdl.html)
>
> Make sure you specify exactly the same namespace attribute in: ServiceContract, ServiceBehavior, and bindingNamespace (.config->services/service/endpoint section).
>
> Be mindful of [this problem](http://geekswithblogs.net/SoftwareDoneRight/archive/2010/04/14/solving-ldquoxmlschemaexception-the-global-element-ltelementnamegt-has-already-been-declared.rdquo.aspx), which I did encounter at one point.
>
> [Download](http://www.thinktecture.com/media/9297/flatwsdl.zip) this zip file and include FlatWsdl/Extensions: FlatWsdl.cs, FlatWsdlServiceHost.cs, and FlatWsdlServiceHostFactory.cs somewhere in your project.
>
> Make sure you specify the fully-qualified classname for your version of FlatWsdlServiceHostFactory.cs (minus .cs of course) in the ServiceHost Factory attribute of your .svc file.

I tried WcfExtras among other things today -- there may be more or less to it, but these steps finally got me going.  Good luck!

[edit]

Comment: I get `The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.` error when trying to download the zip file using the provided link.

Comment: Possibly because this is supported natively in Visual Studio now.

Answer (score 2):

Late answer, hope it helps someone.

Had the same issue, solved it by manually adding the behavior to the serviceendpoint:

```cs
   FlatWsdlServiceHost serviceHost = new FlatWsdlServiceHost(typeof(MyService));

   ServiceEndpoint endp = serviceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IMyService), new BasicHttpBinding(), "MyService");
   endp.Behaviors.Add(new FlatWsdl());
```